# Validate two variables in Javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to JavaScript and am trying to use it to validate a form before it is submitted. The first function, "validateYouTube" works and successfully checks if the YouTube code has been input, but the second function "validateSongandTitle" I am having issues with.

In order for the second function, validateSongandTitle, to be valid, I have the following condition:

- If the user doesn't select a song (as in they leave the drop-down as "No song selected", they will need to then input a "title" for it to be valid.

Here's what I have:

```
 <form action="add-video.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm(event)" id="AddVid"> 
<select name="songid">
      <option value="">No song selected</option>
      <option value="1">Dr Jones</option>
      <option value="2">Spaceship</option>
      <option value="3">Fantasy</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="ytcode" name="ytcode" />
<div id="formyoutubecode"></div>
<input type="text" name="title" size="50" />
<div id="formtitle"></div>
 
 <script>
 function validateForm(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var YouTubeValid = validateYouTube();
    var SongandTitleValid = validateSongandTitle();

    if (!YouTubeValid || !SongandTitleValid) {

        return;
    }

    event.target.submit();
}

function validateYouTube() {
    var a = document.forms["AddVid"]["ytcode"].value;
    if (a == null || a == "") {
        document.getElementById('formyoutubecode').innerHTML = "<small><font color='red'>YouTube Code Required</font></small>";
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

function validateSongandTitle() {
    var b = document.forms["AddVid"]["songid"].value;
    var c = document.forms["AddVid"]["title"].value;
   if ((b == "No song selected" && c == "")) {
        document.getElementById('formtitle').innerHTML = "<small><font color='red'>Video title *Required</font></small>";
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

 </script>
```

Please let me know why it won't work? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked (with `console.log()`) what the value of `b` actually is, in `validateSongandTitle()`? I think that will help...

Comment: you cannot validate with JS int he front end (Node backend is an exception). All you can do is a plausible check. The easier solution would be to use the `required` attribute in a form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue in your code is because your check to see if the `select` has a valid option chosen is using the *text* of the `option` element, not its `value`. If you change `b == "No song selected"` to `b == ''` then the code will work.

That being said there's a few things which you could amend to improve the code quality:

- Use descriptive variable names. `a` and `b` for example aren't very helpful to someone trying to understand your code. Use `title` or `code` instead.
- Don't attach your event handlers in HTML, it's no longer good practice. Bind them in your JS code using `addEventListener()`.
- 'Cache' your Elements in variables which you can re-use where required instead of repeatedly selecting them from the DOM, which is a relatively slow operation.
- Avoid placing HTML in to the JS code as much as possible. With this in mind you can have the error messages within the DOM when the page loads and simply show/hide them with a CSS class that you toggle based on the validity of the input.
- The `<font>` element was deprecated a *very long* time ago and should never be used. Use CSS to style the font as you need.

Here's a working version with the above changes made:

```js
const form = document.querySelector('#addvid');
const ytcodeField = document.querySelector('#ytcode');
const titleField = document.querySelector('#title');
const songidField = document.querySelector('#songid');
const formyoutubecode = document.querySelector('#formyoutubecode');
const formtitle = document.querySelector('#formtitle');

form.addEventListener('submit', e => {  
  const youTubeValid = validateYouTube();
  const songAndTitleValid = validateSongAndTitle();
  
  if (!youTubeValid || !songAndTitleValid) {
    e.preventDefault(); // fields are invalid, prevent submission
  }
});

function validateYouTube() {
  const ytcode = ytcodeField.value.trim();
  const isValid = ytcode !== '';
  formyoutubecode.classList.toggle('hidden', isValid);
  return isValid;
}

function validateSongAndTitle() {
  const songid = songidField.value;
  const title = titleField.value.trim();
  const isValid = songid === '' || (songid !== '' && title !== '');
  formtitle.classList.toggle('hidden', isValid);
  return isValid;
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.error-message {
  color: #F00;
}
```

```html
<form action="add-video.php" method="post" id="addvid">
  <select name="songid" id="songid">
    <option value="">No song selected</option>
    <option value="1">Dr Jones</option>
    <option value="2">Spaceship</option>
    <option value="3">Fantasy</option>
  </select>
  
  <input type="text" id="ytcode" name="ytcode" />
  <div id="formyoutubecode" class="hidden error-message">
    <small>YouTube Code Required</small>
  </div>
  <br />
  
  <input type="text" id="title" name="title" size="50" />
  <div id="formtitle" class="hidden error-message">
    <small>Video title *Required</small>
  </div>
  <br />
    
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write out such an informative answer, I'm sure you can tell Javascript isn't my cup of tea and I barely know the basics, so I was just adapting older codes that I found online... your approach looks much better.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `<select>` tags is based off the *value* of its `<option>`s, not the *text*. In other words:

Change `b == "No song selected"` to `b == ""`.

*Or*

Change `<option value="">No song selected</option>` to `<option value="No song selected">No song selected</option>`.

Comment: Ahh I feel like a muppet! Working perfectly now, thank you! :)

Comment: one thing though. It's JS so you should use strict equality ( `===` ) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality

Comment: one thing to say is, while it does what the OP want you properly should at least have hinted that using JS for this is the wrong approach

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code lies in the condition **(b == "No song selected" && c == "")** in the validateSongandTitle function. When the user selects "No song selected" from the dropdown, the value of b will be an empty string (""), not the string "No song selected". Therefore, your current condition will not match, and the error message won't be displayed.

You should modify your condition to check if b is an empty string, like this:

```
if (b === "" && c === "") {
    document.getElementById('formtitle').innerHTML = "<small><font 
    color='red'>Video title *Required</font></small>";
    return false;
}
```

This way, the condition will be true when the user hasn't selected a song and hasn't provided a title. The updated validateSongandTitle function would be:

```
function validateSongandTitle() {
    var b = document.forms["AddVid"]["songid"].value;
    var c = document.forms["AddVid"]["title"].value;
    if (b === "" && c === "") {
        document.getElementById('formtitle').innerHTML = "<small><font color='red'>Video title *Required</font></small>";
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Now, it should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function validateForm(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        const songId = document.getElementById("songid");
        const selectedOption = songId.options[songId.selectedIndex];
        const selectedText = selectedOption.textContent;
        const ytcode = document.getElementById("ytcode").value.trim();
        const title = document.getElementById("title").value.trim();
        const formsongid = document.getElementById("formsongid");
        const formyoutubecode = document.getElementById("formyoutubecode");
        const formtitle = document.getElementById("formtitle");
        formyoutubecode.innerHTML = "";
        formtitle.innerHTML = "";
        formsongid.innerHTML = "";

        if (selectedText === "No song selected") {
          formsongid.innerHTML =
            "<small><font color='red'>Song id *Required</font></small>";
        }
        if (!ytcode) {
          formyoutubecode.innerHTML =
            "<small><font color='red'>YouTube Code Required</font></small>";
        }
        if (!title) {
          formtitle.innerHTML =
            "<small><font color='red'>Video title *Required</font></small>";
        }

        if (formsongid.innerHTML || ytcode.innerHTML || formtitle.innerHTML) {
          return false;
        }

        alert(JSON.stringify({selectedText, ytcode, title}, null , 2));
        return true;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form
      action="add-video.php"
      method="post"
      onsubmit="return validateForm(event)"
      id="AddVid"
    >
      <select name="songid" id="songid">
        <option value="">No song selected</option>
        <option value="1">Dr Jones</option>
        <option value="2">Spaceship</option>
        <option value="3">Fantasy</option>
      </select>
      <div id="formsongid"></div>
      <input type="text" id="ytcode" name="ytcode" />
      <div id="formyoutubecode"></div>
      <input type="text" name="title" id="title" size="50" />
      <div id="formtitle"></div>
      <input type="submit" onclick="return validateForm(event)" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).